# Play 2.5 disable csrf protection for some requests

Tags: java, playframework, csrf, playframework-2.5

I'm writing my app using play framework v. 2.5.3 and use CSRF protection as it is described in official documentation.

```
public class Filters implements HttpFilters {

@Inject
CSRFFilter csrfFilter;

@Override
public EssentialFilter[] filters() {
    return new EssentialFilter[]{csrfFilter.asJava()};
}}
```

Of course, it works, as long as all of requests need to be filtered, but some of them should be bypassed. How can filters be configured to bypass requests to some specified route? Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is an issue still open about disabling CSRF for certain routes: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/5882

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decorate `CSRFFilter` and use a list of route paths to either include or exclude the application of the filter.

The route paths will need to be in the compiled form, so a route like ´/foo/bar´ would be `/profile` but a route with dynamic components like `/view/:foo/:bar` becomes `/view/$foo<[^/]+>/$bar<[^/]+>`.  You can list the compiled versions of the routes by going to an unmapped URL (e.g. `http://localhost:9000/@foo`) when in development mode.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import akka.util.ByteString;
import play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter;
import play.libs.streams.Accumulator;
import play.mvc.EssentialAction;
import play.mvc.EssentialFilter;
import play.mvc.Result;
import play.routing.Router;

public class MaybeCsrfFilter extends EssentialFilter {

    private final EssentialFilter csrfFilter;

    private final List<String> applyCsrf = new LinkedList<>();

    @Inject
    public MaybeCsrfFilter(final CSRFFilter csrfFilter) {
        this.csrfFilter = csrfFilter.asJava();

        // alternatively, define the inclusion/exclusion list in the config and inject Configuration to obtain it
        applyCsrf.add("/foo/bar");
        applyCsrf.add("/view/$foo<[^/]+>/$bar<[^/]+>");
    }

    @Override
    public EssentialAction apply(final EssentialAction next) {
        return EssentialAction.of(request -> {
            final Accumulator<ByteString, Result> accumulator;
            final String currentRoute = request.tags().get(Router.Tags.ROUTE_PATTERN);
            if (applyCsrf.contains(currentRoute)) {
                accumulator = csrfFilter.apply(next).apply(request);
            } else {
                accumulator = next.apply(request);
            }
            return accumulator;
        });
    }
}
```

It's brute force, and you have to keep your filters in sync with the inclusion/exclusion list, but it works.

Alternatively, you can use comments in the `routes` file to determine which routes should not have the CSRF filter applied.

For a `routes` file like

```
#NOCSRF
GET   /foo/bar               controllers.Application.foo()
#NOCSRF
GET   /view/:hurdy/:gurdy    controllers.Application.bar()
GET   /something/else        controllers.Application.bar()
```

This filter implementation will not apply the CSRF filter to any action whose route is preceded by `# NOCSRF`.  For this example, only `/something/else` will have the CSRF filter applied to it.

```
public EssentialAction apply(final EssentialAction next) {
    return EssentialAction.of(request -> {
        final Accumulator<ByteString, Result> accumulator;
        final String routeComment = request.tags().get(Router.Tags.ROUTE_COMMENTS);
        if ("NOCSRF".equals(routeComment)) {
            accumulator = next.apply(request);
        } else {
            accumulator = csrfFilter.apply(next).apply(request);
        }
        return accumulator;
    });
}
```

Your `Filters` definition then becomes

```
public class Filters implements HttpFilters {

    private final MaybeCsrfFilter csrf;

    @Inject
    public Filters(final MaybeCsrfFilter csrf) {
        this.csrf = csrf;
    }

    @Override
    public EssentialFilter[] filters() {
        return new EssentialFilter[]{csrf};
    }
}
```

Don't forget to create a binding for `MaybeCsrfFilter`!

Comment: This is a lot nicer than play's suggestion of creating a super-secret csrf exempt cookie