# Play 2.5.4 - how to implement CSRF filters?

Tags: playframework, csrf-protection

How does one implement CSRFfilters in Play 2.5.4? The play documentation is wrong (doesn't compile, and can't under the play 2.5.4 java api), the example here doesn't compile ([Play 2.5 disable csrf protection for some requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408269/play-2-5-disable-csrf-protection-for-some-requests)).

the 2.5 java API has a CRSFFilter class but it is not a sub class of EssentialFilter so cannot be added to the array of EssentialFilters because it is the wrong type.

Is this functionality currently broken for Play 2.5.4 or is the documentation currently misleading/wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine for me, Play 2.5.4 Java. 
Create app/Filters.java file and put this

```
import javax.inject.*;
import play.*;
import play.mvc.EssentialFilter;
import play.http.HttpFilters;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter;

public class Filters implements HttpFilters {

    private CSRFFilter csrfFilter;

    @Inject
    public Filters(
        CSRFFilter csrfFilter) {
        this.csrfFilter = csrfFilter;
    }

    @Override
    public EssentialFilter[] filters() {
        return new EssentialFilter[] {
            csrfFilter.asJava()
        };
    }
}
```

add filters dependency in build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += filters
```

and in your application.conf put

```
play.modules.enabled += "play.filters.csrf.CSRFModule"
   # CSRF config
play.filters.csrf {

  token {
    name = "csrfToken"
    sign = true
  }

  cookie {
    name = null
    secure = ${play.http.session.secure}
    httpOnly = false
  }

  body.bufferSize = ${play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer}
  bypassCorsTrustedOrigins = true

  header {
    name = "Csrf-Token"
    protectHeaders {
      Cookie = "*"
      Authorization = "*"
    }
    bypassHeaders {}
  }

  method {
    whiteList = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"]
    blackList = []
  }

  contentType {
    whiteList = []
    blackList = []
  }

  errorHandler = null
}
```

You can learn more about configuration here  https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/resources/confs/filters-helpers/reference.conf

In your template files just import helper

```
@import helper._
```

Then use it in your forms like this

```
<form method="POST" action="...">
@CSRF.formField
```