# Flexible CSRF in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm helping out a project that runs play in scala and has not historically leveraged csrf countermeasures. I'm relatively new to Scala and Play. I've read the documentation about the out of the box functionality (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaCsrf) and it seems that given the current state of the project enabling csrf checks across the application globally is unrealistic and that a per route approach is too cumbersome.

My expectation, coming from other language and framework combinations was something akin to what is proposed here ([Play 2.5 disable csrf protection for some requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408269/play-2-5-disable-csrf-protection-for-some-requests?noredirect=1&lq=1)) and extended upon here (https://dominikdorn.com). But these still feel rather primitive. Note that in the full version of dominikdorn's approach (https://dominikdorn.com/2014/07/playframework-2-3-global-csrf-protection-disable-csrf-selectively/) I still have to wrap an action around existing actions to get csrf tokens injected, which seems a duplication of effort.

The twirl templates we are using often have form literals in them, instead of generated forms.

The ideal solution would allow me to specify declaratively, perhaps through configuration, which routes should require a csrf check and also dynamically inject hidden csrf input fields in any forms referenced in twirl templates that use controller reverse routing calls to routes that I have declared to require csrf checking (action="@foo.bar.routes.routeName").

Can you please direct me to such a solution or a more idiomatic but similar level of effort approach based on convention.

Cheers.